# how to mock class which calls singleton class using junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, junit4

I would like to test a method from `class1` which calls the singleton class `getInstance`:

```
Class ivDomain {

    public String method1() {

        id=Singleton.getInstance().generateId()

        ... code

    }

}
```

When I do the test using Junit I am getting `NullPointerException` on the singleton class. How can I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest you have a bug in your singleton code.  Is there any reason you don't use a plain enum for your Singleton?

Answer (score 4):

Classes using statically accessed singletons are a pain to test.  Change you ivDomain class to rather **take** the singleton instance as a parameter to it's constructor and then mock it normally.  You should use a Dependency Injection framework (such as [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)) going forward to make this style of development easier.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to mock Singleton; just change the code so `getInstance()` doesn't return a null.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason - without examining your Singleton's code - is that it's initialization fails to load some external configuration and therefore fails.

Singletons in Automatic Unit Tests can be a problem since sometimes you like them to behave differently for the specific scenario you test (e.g. you want one scenario where `generateId` returns -1, another when it returns 4354353 and another when it throws a `RuntimeException` - just so you can see how the code that uses the Singleton works. In such cases a change of design is recommended as Singletons are not amongst the favored design patterns and are somewhat regarded as anti-patterns.

Comment: Actually I am not testing singleton code but the method in ivDomain ivDomain.method1 but the method1 has call to singleton class so, it fails at that point and does not go further.

Comment: here is the singleton code                                                                   
package com.cboe.bo.common.utils;

import java.util.TreeMap;

import com.cboe.exceptions.ExceptionDetails;
import com.cboe.exceptions.NotFoundException;
import com.cboe.infrastructureServices.foundationFramework.FoundationFramework;
import com.cboe.infrastructureServices.foundationFramework.utilities.Log;
import com.cboe.infrastructureServices.instrumentationService.EntityID;
import com.cboe.instrumentationService.transactionTimingCommon.TransactionTimer;

public class TransactionTimerUtility {

Comment: private static TransactionTimerUtility tteUtility = null;
 private static TransactionTimer transactionTimer = null;
 protected boolean infoLogStatus = false;
 protected boolean sqlLogStatus = false;
 public static short sourceNumber; 
 private static String isActiveMethod = "Y";
 public static int Enter = 0;
 public static int Leave = 1;
 public static int LeaveWithException = 2;
 private static String transactionTimerIndicator;
 private static final String TTE_REMOTE_VALUE = "local";
 private static String[] methodNames;

Comment: private static TreeMap<String, Long> methodIds;
 private static TreeMap<String, String> isActiveMethods;
 private static Long nextID = (long) 0;
 private static ThreadLocal<Long> tLocal = new ThreadLocal<Long>() {
  protected synchronized Long initialValue() {
   return new Long(nextID++);
  }};
 private static Long get() {
  return (Long) tLocal.get();
 }
 public TransactionTimerUtility() {
  infoLogStatus = LogHelper.getInfoLogStatus();
  sqlLogStatus = LogHelper.getSqlLogStatus();
 }

Comment: static {
  transactionTimerIndicator = (System.getProperty("transactionTimer") == null) ? TTE_REMOTE_VALUE
    : System.getProperty("transactionTimer");

  if (transactionTimerIndicator.equalsIgnoreCase(TTE_REMOTE_VALUE)) {
   transactionTimer = FoundationFramework.getInstance()     .getInstrumentationService().getTransactionTimerFactory().getLocalTransactionTimer();
  } else {
   transactionTimer = FoundationFramework.getInstance()
   .getInstrumentationService().getTransactionTimerFactory().getRemoteTransactionTimer();
  }

Comment: if (System.getProperty("sourceNumber") != null) {
   sourceNumber = Short.valueOf(System.getProperty("sourceNumber"));
  }
  String methods = System.getProperty("methodNames");
  if (methods != null) {
   methodNames = methods.split(",");
   System.out.println(" method names are " + methodNames);
  }
  methodIds = new TreeMap<String, Long>();
  isActiveMethods = new TreeMap<String, String>();

Comment: for (String entry : methodNames) {
   methodIds.put(entry,
     transactionTimer.registerTransactionIdentifier(entry));
   isActiveMethods.put(entry, isActiveMethod);
  }
 }
 public long generateTransId(String reqNbr) {
  long transId = 0;
  if (reqNbr != null) {
   if (reqNbr.equals("0"))
    transId = get();
   else
    transId = Long.valueOf(reqNbr);
   transId = EntityID.createID(EntityID.TT_CAS, sourceNumber,
     Long.valueOf(reqNbr));
   Log.information(" TransId from hashCode is : " + transId);
  }
  // If transId is 0, we have an issue.
  return transId;
 }

Comment: // Get an instance of the TransactionTimerUtility (singleton)
 public static TransactionTimerUtility getInstance() {
  return tteUtility;
 }

}

Comment: @Tejas Shah: Can you post this code in the question as an edit? it is not very readable in this manner

Comment: Thanks guys I have found my problem.

Answer (score 1):

check
 [mocking a singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302179/mocking-a-singleton-class)