# Mock the external call under private method in java

Tags: java, mocking, powermock, private-methods

I want to test the `ClassToTest` class for it's method `methodToTest`. But I am not able to make it as the private method `anotherMethod` which is being called by the `methodToTest` has some dependency with the value returned by the singleton class `SingletonClass` using its public method `getName`.

I tried using powermock's privateMethod mock and static method mock and all, but no help.
Does anyone have a solution for this scenario?

```
Class ClassToTest{
    public void methodToTest(){
        ...
        anotherMethod();
        ...
    }

    private void anotherMethod(){
        SingletonClass singletonObj = SingletonClass.getInstance();
        String name = singletonObj.getName();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate ? [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302179/mocking-a-singleton-class). Alternatively if you are able to modify the ClassToTest (?) it would be favorable to weaken the dependency on the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mockStatic` (see http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Mocking_Static_Method)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SingletonClass.class})
public class ClassToTestTest {
    @Test
    public void testMethodToTest() {
        SingletonClass mockInstance = PowerMockito.mock(SingletonClass.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SingletonClass.class);
        PowerMockito.when(SingletonClass.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockInstance);
        PowerMockito.when(mockInstance.getName()).thenReturn("MOCK NAME");

        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a partial mock to deal with this situation.  It sounds like you want to create an instance of the object, but you just want to see if the object calls the anotherMethod() method without actually doing any of the logic in the other method.  If I'm understanding correctly, the following should accomplish your goal.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassToTest.class})
public class ClassToTestTest {
    @Test
    public void testMethodToTest() {
        ClassToTest mockInstance = 
                   PowerMock.createPartialMock(SingletonClass.class,"anotherMethod");
        PowerMock.expectPrivate(mockInstance, "anotherMethod");
        PowerMock.replay(mockInstance);
        mockInstance.methodToTest();
        PowerMock.verify(mockInstance);
    }
}
```