# How to mock an enum singleton class using Mockito/Powermock?

Tags: java, enums, singleton, mockito, powermock

I am unsure on how to mock an enum singleton class.

```
public enum SingletonObject{
  INSTANCE;
  private int num;

  protected setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  public int getNum() {
    return num;
  }
```

I'd like to stub getNum() in the above example, but I can't figure out how to mock the actual SingletonObject class.  I thought using Powermock to prepare the test would help since enums are inherently final.

```
//... rest of test code
@Test
public void test() {
  PowerMockito.mock(SingletonObject.class);
  when(SingletonObject.INSTANCE.getNum()).thenReturn(1); //does not work
}
```

This is using PowerMockMockito 1.4.10 and Mockito 1.8.5.

Comment: Check similar thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302179/mocking-a-singleton-class

Comment: Thanks Martin, I read through that thread and it looks like its an approach for using the non-enum way of implementing a singleton, and I am able to use mocking properly with that method. However, is there a way to mock an enum singleton class? From what I've gathered, enum singleton class is the recommended method of declaring a singleton after java 1.5.

Comment: [Re: PowerMock : can i mock enums?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/powermock/hqrJaMi0Zrc)

Comment: Singletons are evils :)

Answer (score 33):

If you want to stub out what INSTANCE returns, you can do it but it's kind of nasty (using reflection & bytecode manipulation). I created & tested a simple project with three classes using the PowerMock 1.4.12 / Mockito 1.9.0. All classes were in the same package.

## SingletonObject.java

```
public enum SingletonObject {
    INSTANCE;
    private int num;

    protected void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}
```

## SingletonConsumer.java

```
public class SingletonConsumer {
    public String consumeSingletonObject() {
        return String.valueOf(SingletonObject.INSTANCE.getNum());
    }
}
```

## SingletonConsumerTest.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SingletonObject.class})
public class SingletonConsumerTest {
    @Test
    public void testConsumeSingletonObject() throws Exception {
        SingletonObject mockInstance = mock(SingletonObject.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(SingletonObject.class, "INSTANCE", mockInstance);

        when(mockInstance.getNum()).thenReturn(42);

        assertEquals("42", new SingletonConsumer().consumeSingletonObject());
    }
}
```

The call to the `Whitebox.setInternalState` replaces `INSTANCE` with a mock object that you can manipulate within your test.

Comment: But how can you mock SingletonObject.class?
It will give MockitoException with comment "Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types"

Comment: This uses PowerMock.

Comment: Hi, i got `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final` while using `Whitebox.setInternalState`. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you use the `@PrepareForTest` annotation on your test class?

Comment: I tried the same way but my enum's constructor is still getting executed, which I don't want. Does above solution mock's the enum's constructor as well?

Comment: At the time of the writing of this answer, the above would have worked. Four years later, I am not sure how updates to Java, PowerMock, and Mockito would play together. One thing to check are your annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Have an interface with the methods you intend to mock

```
public interface SingletonInterface {
  int getNum();
}
```

Let the enum implement the interface

```
public enum SingletonObject implements SingletonInterface {
    INSTANCE;
    private int num;

    protected void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}
```

Mock the interface

```
@Test
public void test() {
  SingletonInterface singleton = Mockito.mock(SingletonInterface.class);
  when(singleton.getNum()).thenReturn(1); //does work
}
```

Comment: This answer is the best one

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above Matt Lachman answer, create a object factory for power mock in `SingleTonConsumerTest.class`

```
@ObjectFactory
public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
    return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
}
```

This will remove `Mockito cannot mock/spy following: - final classes - anonymous classes - primitive types` error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is best approach, but in my case it's working without troubles so far. I am using mockito-core and mockito-inline (3.11.0) and I am mocking my singleton with help of spy. Example with your class:

```
SingletonObject so = SingletonObject.INSTANCE;
private SingletonObject spySo = Mockito.spy(so);

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Mockito.doReturn(10).when(spySo).getNum();
}

@Test
public void simpleTest() {
    assertThat(spySo.getNum(), is(10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mockito** docs are not explicit on **enum** use case:

- [Mocking final types, enums and final methods (Since 2.1.0)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39)

Powermock support:

- Compatible with **JUnit 4**

**build.gradle** (****** should work with **Maven** too)

```
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.1.0'
```

As of the available experimental features (***Powermock + JUnit 5***), can give a try to:

```
    implementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit5', version: '1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.4'
```

Enum:

```java
public enum ConnectionFactory {
   INSTANCE;

   public Connection get() throws SQLException {
      //
      // Load url from configuration file  ('application.yml')
      //
      final var connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      connection.setAutoCommit(false);

      return connection;
   }
}
```

Can use these approaches:

```java
class DatabaseUnitTests {

   private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = Mockito.spy(ConnectionFactory.INSTANCE);


   //Or

   @InjectMocks
   private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = Mockito.mock(ConnectionFactory.class);


   @Test
   void check_is_database_connection_is_OK(){
      Mockito.doReturn(mockedConnection()).when(connectionFactory).get();
       
      // Do something
   }
```