# How to Invoke a private method on a singleton (Enum style) in java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums, easymock, powermock

Is there a way to invoke a private static method of an enumerated singleton?  For example, say I have some legacy code that I need to test which has the following structure:

```
public enum Singleton {

    INSTANCE;

    private static double methodToTest() {
        return 1.0;
    }       

    public static String extremelyComplexMethod() {
        methodToTest();
        //Imagine lots more complex code here
        return "";
    }
}
```

How would I go about creating a class that tests `methodToTest` in isolation?  I've tried reflection using Whitebox (included in PowerMock) but I've had no luck.  Is there a way to do it?

I know that testing a private method directly is not the prefered method of doing things, but I want to know if its possible to test the private method directly. I tried to get the code to get recognized as java, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-a-class-with-private-methods-using-junit

Comment: The difference is that its an enum.  I've tried using Whitebox to do it the same way as I would do for a private static method of a class, but I have not had success.

Comment: The point is, that there is not really a difference between calling private static methods in classes or in enums! So, if you found a way of calling private static methods in classes, this should also work for enums.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939023/how-to-mock-an-enum-singleton-class-using-mockito-powermock. See my answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to invoke the method try this following code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Singleton.class)
public class MySingletonTest {   
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{ 
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(Singleton.class, "methodToTest");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the Singleton class in PrepareForTest