# How to cover block catch by JUnit with NoSuchAlgorithmException and KeyStoreException

Tags: java, junit, try-catch, mockito

I want to cover getKeyStore() methode, But I don't know how to cover catch block for NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException and CertificateException. My methode is :

---

```
public static KeyManagerFactory getKeyStore(String keyStoreFilePath)
        throws IOException {
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;
    InputStream kmf= null;
    try {
        keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystoreStream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFilePath);
        keyStore.load(keystoreStream, "changeit".toCharArray());
        kmf.init(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_MESSAGE_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM + e);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_MESSAGE_KEY_STORE + e);
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_MESSAGE_UNRECOVERABLEKEY + e);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_MESSAGE_CERTIFICATE + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (keystoreStream != null){
                keystoreStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(ERROR_MESSAGE_IO + e);
        }
    }
    return kmf;
}
```

---

How do I do it?

Comment: I am not sure it needs covering. However, maybe I would create `handleException(Exception)` or if i were using java7 maybe I would catch multiple exceptions (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html). I am not sure this logging is worth effort covering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **mock** any sentence of the `try` block to throw the exception you want to catch.

Example mocking the `KeyManagerFactory.getInstance` call to throw `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. In that case, you will cover the first catch block, you have to do the same with other exceptions caught (KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException and CertificateException)

You can do as follows (as method `getInstance` is `static`, you have to use [PowerMockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) instead `Mockito`, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito) for more info)

```
@PrepareForTest(KeyManagerFactory.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

   @Test
   public void testGetKeyStore() throws Exception {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(KeyManagerFactory.class);
      when(KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(anyString())).thenThrow(new NoSuchAlgorithmException());
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, With tour test it work well. But when I did same for KeyStoreException. didn't work. My code Is :          @Test                                                         public void testGetStore() throws Exception {
PowerMockito.mockStatic(KeyStore.class);       PowerMockito.when(KeyStore.getInstance(Mockito.anyString())).thenThrow(new KeyStoreException());
  }  . Manny thanks

Comment: You are mocking another class, KeyStore. Maybe you've forgotten to change the @PrepareForTest annotation. Should be: @PrepareForTest(KeyStore.class)

Comment: No. I made KeyStore in @PrepaerForTest. I thnik the problem is the  KeyStore.getInstance(Mockito.anyString()) didnt throw KeyStoreException. The test pass but didnt catch the exception

Comment: I think it's because KeyStore is a singleton [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302179/mocking-a-singleton-class)

Comment: @troig,  I tried the above approach, but it is not working for me.  Unfortunately, I cannot add the complete code in the comment part and it is not the answer, so don't want to add the details of my attempt as an answer.  I realise this is an old question but it is exactly same question / problem I have as this question.  What would be the best way for me to provide details of my scenario?

Comment: @adbdkb maybe you could post a new question with all the details?

Comment: @triog, thanks.   I already have a question posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267168/how-to-simulate-caught-and-logged-exceptions-inside-a-method-and-create-junit-te on similar lines before I found this question and answer.  I will update the question with class methid and my junit method code and add a comment addressed to you.  Will that work?

Comment: Great, I'll try to have a look asap

Comment: @troig - I have updated the other question with full example and error.  Thanks again for helping out.  The updates are under --  Update 2 - Another Example

Comment: @troig - Did you have an opportunity to look at my issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267168/how-to-simulate-caught-and-logged-exceptions-inside-a-method-and-create-junit-te ?

Thanks again for your help