# How do I mock a private static final field initialized via a private constructor using Powermock and Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, white-box

Here's my source class -

```
public class ClassToTest extends AbstractSuperClass<Integer> {
    private static final ClassToTest INSTANCE = new ClassToTest(); // (line 1) need to mock this variable

    static ClassToTest get() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    private ClassToTest() {
        super(Integer.class);// (line 2)
    }
}
```

Here's my attempt so far at testing it

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassToTest.class)
public class TestClass {
    private ClassToTest testClass;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // each of the below attempts fails at line 1  because of the call to line 2 (annotated above).
        // Attempt A.  
        testClass = WhiteBox.newInstance(ClassToTest.class);
        //Attempt B.
        testClass = mock(ClassToTest.class);
        WhiteBox.setInternalState(ClassToTest.class, "INSTANCE", testClass);
    }
    @Test
    public void dummy() {
        // irrelevant
    }
}
```

I'm trying to effectively mock out `ClassToTest.INSTANCE` and the call its private constructor. How could I do that?

EDIT :  Snippet/Constructor invoked from `AbstractSuperClass`.

```
public abstract class AbstractSuperClass<V extends Serializable> {
    private final CacheClient<V> cache;
    private final int seconds;

    public AbstractSuperClass(Class<V> valueType) {
        cache = new ClientFactory(Config.getAppConfig(), StatisticSet.getGlobalStatistics()).newClient(getCacheType(), valueType);
        seconds = Config.getAppConfig().get(getCacheType().getSectionEnum()).getSeconds();
    }
```

P.S: I'm trying to stay away from dealing with the internals of `AbstractSuperClass` and had originally hoped to simply mock the call away. I'm also open to any ideas to refactoring `ClassToTest` to avoid this .

Comment: Your solution to mock `ClassToTest.INSTANCE` seams to work, if you add `testClass.doSomething(); verify(testClass).doSomething();` to the `dummy` method, then the tests passes, so I don't see what actually the problem is (I used attempt B). Could you add some more information regarding what the issue is?

Comment: @GergelyToth - I'm guessing this may have to do with the call to `AbstractSuperClass` from the private constructor, I have edited  the question and added more details of the class.

Comment: I'm curious to see if there are any solutions to this problem using Mockito/PowerMock. In my case I was  looking to test another class that had `ClassToTest` as a dependency, so I basically extracted `ClassToTest` to an interface and provided a mock implementation for the purposes of test, similar to whats explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2302208/919858)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but this is working here:

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassToTest.class) // required
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)    // required
public class ClassToTestTest {

    private ClassToTest testClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.testClass = Mockito.mock(ClassToTest.class);
        final Field instance = ClassToTest.class.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE");
        instance.setAccessible(true);
        instance.set(null, this.testClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception {
        assertSame(this.testClass, ClassToTest.get());
        System.out.println(this.testClass);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Mock for ClassToTest, hashCode: 1083021083
```

(Tested with powermock-api-mockito version 1.6.2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that mocking the field is the right approach, I don't even believe that it is possible to do it as **you cannot override a field** only methods can be overridden which is actually how mocks do and work. Indeed mocks are only somehow proxies to which we override the methods.

You should mock `ClassToTest.get()` instead as next:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassToTest.class)
public class TestClass {
    private ClassToTest testClass;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testClass = PowerMockito.mock(ClassToTest.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassToTest.class);
        Mockito.when(ClassToTest.get()).thenReturn(testClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void dummy() {
        // Here I get the instance of ClassToTest that I mocked in the setUp method
        System.out.println(ClassToTest.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails at `PowerMockito.mock(ClassToTest.class)` again caused by line 1 and line 2 respectively, which implies the call hasn't been mocked out :( .

Comment: I copied/pasted your code without AbstractSuperClass as you did not provide it and it works

Comment: please provide AbstractSuperClass then

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, I think that may be the difference in us seeing different results(?) The `AbstractSuperClass` actually loads a bunch of configurations in my case and `super()` might be causing the failure.

Comment: it's hard to help if you don't provide the missing class following the MCVE rule http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, sorry for the delay, (was pulled into some other stuff) Ive actually added a snippet from the `AbstractSuperClass`.. I hope that helps us progress.

Answer (score 1):

Your **real** problem is that you created hard, almost un-testable code by making use of **static**. And not only that: you also create a bad **design**. Because you tightly couple your production classes to each other. Once in place, it will be **hard** to get rid of that static method later on.

So, the other option: instead of trying to "fix" a broken design by using PowerMock, you step back. You learn what "writing testable" code is actually about (for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79)); and then you use pure interfaces and dependency injection to solve your problem. And you test all of that with EasyMock or Mockito, without the need to Powermock!

Comment: This. Powermock is a cruel mistress - it will help you in the short term but hurt you in the long term. As mentioned, it pacifies bad design as well as consumes your `@RunWith` and can cause tricky compatibility issues with other libraries because of what it does.

Comment: As usual, everything in life, and also in IT life is about balancing. If you are dealing with 3rd party/legacy code; that you can or want not change; then Powermock might still be helpful. But the very simple rule is: if you are creating new code, then you do not **need** Powermock. End of story.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question at hand, but your personal opinion on how code should be done.